# Cannot send the email through using XAMPP

Tags: php, email, xampp, smtp

I am stucked email function in the XAMPP in few days , I am trying using PHPMailer functions to send the email through in the XAMPP, but it cannot work,

The error come out below these messages:

```html
2021-06-30 08:29:38 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP b25sm12430661ios.36 - gsmtp
2021-06-30 08:29:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2021-06-30 08:29:38 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [157.230.55.84]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250 SMTPUTF8
2021-06-30 08:29:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2021-06-30 08:29:38 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2021-06-30 08:29:39 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2021-06-30 08:29:39 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2021-06-30 08:29:39 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed:
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

Fatal error: Uncaught PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPMailer\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php:2136 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPMailer\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php(1960): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->smtpConnect(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPMailer\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php(1638): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->smtpSend('Date: Wed, 30 J...', 'This is the HTM...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPMailer\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php(1471): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->postSend() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPMailer\index.php(37): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->send() #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPMailer\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php on line 2136
```

I am using below PHP functions to do this:

```html
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // Load Composer's autoloader
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    // Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                       // Enable/disable verbose debug output, change this to 2 if you want to see it doing its thing :)
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                       // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'test@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = '123456abc';                        // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                                  // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

    $mail->setFrom('no-reply@example.com', 'Alex');     // From address

    $mail->addAddress('test@gmail.com');                  // Add a recipient, In this case your email address 

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                        // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Testing Email';
    // $mail->Body    = 'Name: ' .$_POST['name']. '<br>Email: ' .$_POST['email']. '<br>Message: ' .$_POST['message'];
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML body';


    $mail->send();
    echo '<h2 style="color:red">Thank you '.$_POST['name'].', your message has been sent successfully</h2>';
```

This is my online PHP editor: https://paiza.io/projects/D-J1uBPeHJuL8jCOhToRQQ

This is my file path:

[filepath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPoX2.png)

What I've tried:

1. I have followed this video link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKbr2lRD7lQ step by step to create an email function. But also cannot send the mail to the selected email address.
2. Less secure app access has turned on.

Hope someone can guide me or point out which part I am getting wrong. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This has already been answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46237342/10806531

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to send mail using phpmailer on xampp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46236860/how-to-send-mail-using-phpmailer-on-xampp)

Comment: I have tried follow your suggested link. Also cannot work

Answer (score 1):

Literally copied from https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps

```
//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;

//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();

//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
// use
// $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
// if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6

//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS
$mail->Port = 587;

//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username = "username@gmail.com";

//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "yourpassword";

//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'First Last');

//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');

//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('whoto@example.com', 'John Doe');
```

Answer (score 0):

As seen your configuration it looks proper. Please try with port 465

Comment: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPMailer\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\SMTP.php on line 1228

The error come out